Angular 19 REQUEST is `null` (on server runtime) even with RenderMode.Server and SSG disabled
In Angular 19, there's a new way to access the Request object from the Angular application scope which was not available on Angular 18.
According to the docs, expect null if you hit any of the following condition:


During the build processes.
When the application is rendered in the browser (client-side rendering).
When performing static site generation (SSG).
During route extraction in development (at the time of the request).


I made sure to disable SSG with the following change in the default angular.json:
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "options": {
            "prerender": false,

And I made sure that the renderMode is not prerender in app.routes.server.ts:
import { RenderMode, ServerRoute } from '@angular/ssr';

export const serverRoutes: ServerRoute[] = [
  {
    path: '**',
    renderMode: RenderMode.Server
  }
];

Both approach of DI still returns null for REQUEST:
import { Component, inject, Inject, REQUEST } from '@angular/core';

//...
export class AppComponent {
  // constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) public req: Request) {
  //   console.log('req', this.req); //null
  // }

  constructor() {
    const req = inject(REQUEST);
    console.log('req', req); // null
  }
}


Is it available on onOnit?

That would be odd since you cannot perform injection in ngOnInit since you will get a RuntimeError: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor.... But I tried declaring a property anyway to perform the injection properly and access it on ngOnInit like so: req = inject(REQUEST); ngOnInit() { console.log('req', this.req); } and it is still null. Secondly, the documentation only shows an example with the constructor.

Are you sure your app use your server routes config ? Your app.config.server.ts must include this environment provider provideServerRoutesConfig(serverRoutes). Note that your req variable still needs to be transfered to the browser (so your console.log in your browser will always be null in your snippet)

@LucasTesseron "Note that your req variable still needs to be transfered to the browser" <- This does not make sense.  the script will clearly run on both Node (SSR server-side runtime) and client side runtime since I am not blocking it with isPlatformBrowser or isPlatformServer check. And yes, app.config.server is using it.

The script runs both on your browser and server, but this does not mean that your req variable is automatically populated by Angular in your browser. You need to explicitly transfer it (use the Angular TransferState API).
Here is a snippet to access the REQUEST token from your browser to get you started:
import { Component, inject, makeStateKey, REQUEST, TransferState } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {

  private readonly transferState: TransferState = inject(TransferState);
  private readonly req = inject(REQUEST, { optional: true });
  private readonly REQ_URL = makeStateKey<any>('reqUrl');
  private transferedUrl:string | undefined;

  constructor() {

    if (this.req) {
      console.log('[Server] received request', this.req.url);
      this.transferState.set(this.REQ_URL, this.req.url);
    } else {
      // This is executed on the browser only (or during the build process)
      console.log('[Browser] Request object not available, getting it from server cache..');
      this.transferedUrl = this.transferState.get(this.REQ_URL, null);
      console.log('[Browser] Retrived request url is', this.transferedUrl);
    }

  }
}


I am not expecting req to be not null on the browser side.

The issue is more like this - AngularNodeAppEngine: Injected REQUEST empty on first initialization #28995 but instead of getting the request body after the said event "route extraction in development (at the time of the request)" (i.e. the initialization), i am still having null on the succeeding access to req (in server runtime)
